# I want to use LGPL htmltopdf library in a commercial project, I'm I free to use?

Tags: php, pdf, html-to-pdf

I'm working on a project where I need to use some htmltopdf library.Now their licence is LGPL, I don't know whether I'm free to use this one. My project is a commercial one.Please explain LGPL and what are the consequences if use it in a commercial project!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Comment: But at least as a developer someone may have experience with these so they may help , it's not that only a legal adviser should solve this and if you don't know then quit to answer. I'm a beginner so I don't expect to go legal adviser. @cel

Answer (score 3):

LGPL is GNU Lesser Public License and it allows you to use and distribute your application without revealing the source code. LGPL does not put restrictions on whether your software is commercial or not.

Actually both GPL and LGPL do not care if your software is commercial or not. GPL license mandates that you should open-source the software in which it is used. LGPL does not.

When using LGPL, if you modify the LGPL source then you still have to link and open-source your changes to the LGPL versioned part of your application (in your case HTMLToPDF). However you can link the LGPL-ed software to a commerical/proprietary software which is closed source.

[Read this as well](https://opensource.org/licenses/LGPL-3.0).